# fgets fails when a variable is initialized before the call

Tags: c, file-io, fgets

i have this code to read a chip8 rom and print out the corresponding instructions:

```
int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("./roms/IBMLogo.ch8", "rb");
    uint8_t *code;
    while(fgets(code, 3, fp)) {
        disassemble_chip8(code);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

it works completely fine, i get the output i expect to get. however, when i add in a variable initialization:

```
int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("./roms/IBMLogo.ch8", "rb");
    uint8_t *code;
    uint32_t hex_address = 0; // this line right here
    while(fgets(code, 3, fp)) {
        disassemble_chip8(code);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

fgets fails and the loop is not entered. i have tried debugging this but i cannot for the life of me figure out the problem. is this some random behaviour of C that i'm missing?

Comment: Should be `uint8_t code[3];`. And `fgets` should probably be `fread`. `fgets` is not intended for use with binary files.

Comment: i appreciate the answer but 
1. my function takes in a pointer, it's fine the way it is, and 
2. you didn't actually answer the question

Comment: You need to allocate memory for `code` to point to.

Comment: You're causing undefined behavior by using an uninitialized variable. It's just an accident that it seems to work find in the first version and fails in the second.

Comment: Your existing code invokes undefined behaviour since the pointer `code` is uninitialized.  Anything can happen — including it seems to work or it seems to fail.  Allocate space for `code` (at least 3 bytes) and you'll be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "random behavior" is your program using fgets to read into memory pointed to by `uint8_t *code`.

Ask yourself, "What does code point to?"

Realize that the answer is "I don't know, because I didn't set it to anything."

And **THAT** is the "random" behavior. Whatever value was in the stack memory or register that the compiler assigned to `code` is what was being used. It is "random" as in you have no idea what that value is going to be.

Comment: thank you, i was assuming stuff because of how fgets affects the pointer. been a while so i've forgotten some stuff.